# Windows Server 2012 hangs on splash screen during boot

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 box that I've rebooted a number of times without issue, but yesterday I reboot to remove a DNS role and now it hangs on the splash screen with the windows logo and the spinning dots at the bottom.  I've ran a full hardware diag and everything is clean, no bios errors or other that I can see.  It boots into safemode with networking just fine but even there the event manager doesn't show any errors about failed boot attempts.  I'm sort of at a loss since I'm not finding an actual error anywhere, does anyone have any ideas?  The server is really only running Hyper-V with a couple hosts, I'm moving those hosts to another hyper-V machine while trying to troubleshoot this issue.  Thanks for any input you might have!

Comment: Is there a possibility that it was Windows Update that could have caused it?  Maybe just a coincidence that it happened when you removed the DNS role?  I have had an update cause that, in which case I just rebooted and booted to the last known good config.

Comment: Same issue here, stuck with windows logo and spinner that never stops. I'm forced to power cycle and find no errors in the event log after it boots.